# Laravel Ajax Add To Cart Not working 500 internal error

Tags: ajax, laravel, internal-server-error

I have code I am working on.  I will list the page, the route, and the controller code.  When I inspect and click on the add to cart button I get 500 internal server error and I cannot figure out what I did.  It should be giving a message checking to see if the item is already in the cart and if not send a message saying item is in the cart but I can't get past the 500 internal server error.

Page

```
@extends('layouts.frontend.frontend')
@section('title')
Distinctly Mine - {{$products->name}}
@endsection
@section('content')



<div class="py-3 mb-4 shadow-sm babyblue border-top">
    <div class="container">
        <h6 class="mb-0">Collections / {{$products->category->name}} / {{$products->name}}</h6>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="card-shadow shadow-sm product_data">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 border-right">
                <div class="img-hover-zoom img-hover-zoom--xyz card-img-top">
                <img src="{{ asset('backend/uploads/products/'.$products->image) }}" class="w-100 h-100" alt="{{$products->name}}">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2 class="mb-0">{{ $products->name}}</h2> 

                <hr>
                <label for="" class="me-3">Price: ${{$products->original_price}}</label>
                <p class="mt-3">{!! $products->small_description !!}</p>
                <hr>
                @if($products->qty > 0)
                <label for="" class="badge bg-success text-dark fw-bold">In Stock</label>
                @else 
                <label for="" class="badge bg-danger text dark fw-bold">Out of Stock</label>
                @endif

                <div class="row mt-2">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{$products->id}}" class="prod_id">
                        <label for="Quantity">Quantity</label>
                        <div class="input-group text-center mb-3" style="width:130px">
                            <button type="button" class="input-group-text decrement-btn">-</button>
                            <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="form-control qty-input" />
                            <button type="button" class="input-group-text increment-btn">+</button>
                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <br />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning text-dark fw-bold ms-3 float-start"><i class=" me-1 fa fa-heart text-danger me-1"></i>Add To Wishlist</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success ms-3 float-start text-dark fw-bold addToCartBtn"><i class="me-1 fa fa-shopping-cart text-dark me-1"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                    </div>

                    <hr>
                    <h2>Description</h2>
                    {{$products->description}}
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>




@endsection


@section('scripts')
<script>
           $(document).ready(function (){

                $('.addToCartBtn').click(function (e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var product_id = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.prod_id').val();
                    var product_qty = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.qty-input').val();
                    
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                    });

                   

                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "/add-to-cart",
                        data: {
                            'product_id': product_id,
                            'product_qty': product_qty,
                        },
                        dataType: "dataType",
                        success: function (response){
                                alert(response.status);
                        }
                    });
        
                    
                });

            $('.increment-btn').click(function (e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var inc_value = $('.qty-input').val();
                var value = parseInt(inc_value,10);
                value = isNaN(value) ? 0 :value;
                if(value < 10)
                {
                    value++;
                    $('.qty-input').val(value);
                }
            });

         
            $('.decrement-btn').click(function (e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var dec_value = $('.qty-input').val();
                var value = parseInt(dec_value,10);
                value = isNaN(value) ? 0 :value;
                if(value > 1)
                {
                    value--;
                    $('.qty-input').val(value);
                }
         

           }); 
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

Route

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function (){
    Route::post('/add-to-cart',[CartController::class,'addProduct']);
});
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function addProduct(Request $request)
    {
        $product_id = $request->input('product_id');
        $product_qty = $request->input('product_qty');
        if(Auth::check())
        {
            $prod_check = Product::where('id',$product_id)->first();
            if($prod_check)
            {
                if(Cart::where('prod_id',$product_id)->where('user_id',Auth::id())->exists())
                {
                    return response()->json(['status' => $prod_check->name." Already Added to cart"]);

                }else{
                    $cartItem = new Cart();
                    $cartItem->prod_id = $product_id;
                    $cartItem->user_id = Auth::id();
                    $cartItem->prod_qty = $product_qty;
                    $cartItem->save();
                    return response()->json(['status'=>$prod_check->name." Added to cart"]);
                }
                
            
            }
        }
        else{
            return response()->json(['status'=> "Login To Continue"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the log.txt file output that is normally generated in such situations.
There is also the problem, that no response is returned if `if($prod_check)` fails. This would mean that a) the Product doesn't exist or b) the id is not correctly passed.

Comment: I looked in the logs and I don't see anything app\storage\logs\laravel???

Comment: It is almost impossible that no log file is generated if the laravel 500er page is returned, are you sure it is the laravel error page?

Comment: Change the product lookup to `$prod_check = Product::findOrFail($product_id)`, this will return a 404 if the product isn't found. You may want to validate the request: check if the user is logged in, check if the product id exits and make sure the qty field is unsigned int. Is your app in [debug mode](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#debug-mode)?